# Python: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, machine-learning, path, filepath

I have a little experience with python, and I am currently attempting to try some machine learning video generation via pix2pix through this [guide](https://medium.com/@jctestud/video-generation-with-pix2pix-aed5b1b69f57).

I am currently at the part where I need to extract frames from the video. I am using the same video, but moved it into the same directory as extract_frames.py for convenience.

I keep getting a WinError 2: the system cannot find the file specified:

```
C:\Users\cadou\OneDrive\Desktop\ml\pix2pixHD>python extract_frames.py -video fire.mp4 -name fire_dataset -p2pdir . -width 1280 -height 736
creating the dataset structure
ffmpeg -v 16 -i C:\Users\cadou\OneDrive\Desktop\ml\pix2pixHD\fire.mp4 -q:v 2 -vf "scale=iw*736/ih:736, crop=1280:736" C:\Users\cadou\OneDrive\Desktop\ml\pix2pixHD/datasets/fire_dataset/train_frames/frame-%06d.jpg -hide_banner
extracting the frames
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\cadou\OneDrive\Desktop\ml\pix2pixHD\extract_frames.py", line 32, in <module>
    video_utils.extract_frames_from_video(
  File "C:\Users\cadou\OneDrive\Desktop\ml\pix2pixHD\video_utils.py", line 82, in extract_frames_from_video
    p = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command), shell=False)
  File "C:\Users\cadou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\cadou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1420, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I have looked up this error and tried a few things, but none of them seem to fix my issue. I suspect it has something to do with the Path, but I have tried changing that too. I installed all the libraries requested from the tutorial as well (dominate, ffmpeg, and pyTorch).

Comment: is this full error? It doesn't show what file it can't find. Maybe it can't find `fire.mp4`  but maybe it need `ffmpeg` to extract video.

Comment: I checked source code for `subprocess` in `video_utils.py` and it runs [ffmpeg](https://github.com/jctestud/pix2pixHD/blob/video/video_utils.py#L71) - and it needs to install it from https://ffmpeg.org/ . It may need also change `video_utils.py` and use `C:\full\path\to\ffmpeg.exe`. There is also hardcoded path to `Ubuntu-Font` which shows  that this code was created for Linux Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following command with replacing "fire.mp4" to "./fire.mp4".

```
python extract_frames.py -video ./fire.mp4 -name fire_dataset -p2pdir . -width 1280 -height 736
```

Answer (score 0):

Erorr doesn't show what file it can't find.

Maybe it can't find `fire.mp4` but I expect it needs `ffmpeg` to extract video.

---

I checked source code for `subprocess` in `video_utils.py` and it runs [ffmpeg](https://github.com/jctestud/pix2pixHD/blob/video/video_utils.py#L71) - so you needs to install it from https://ffmpeg.org/ .

It may need also to change `video_utils.py` and use `C:\full\path\to\ffmpeg.exe`.

There is also hardcoded path to `Ubuntu` font (in two places: see [code](https://github.com/jctestud/pix2pixHD/blob/video/video_utils.py#L25)) which shows that this code was created for `Linux Ubuntu`. This path also will need changes to other font on Windows.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I installed ffmpeg from the website and added it to PATH and everything. I had pip installed it before, but I guess that was not quite enough. I am no longer getting the same error, but it is now returning this: 
`creating the dataset structure
ffmpeg -v 16 -i C:\Users\cadou\OneDrive\Desktop\ml\pix2pixHD\fire.mp4 -q:v 2 -vf "scale=iw*736/ih:736, crop=1280:736" C:\Users\cadou\OneDrive\Desktop\ml\pix2pixHD/datasets/fire_dataset/train_frames/frame-%06d.jpg -hide_banner
extracting the frames
C:UserscadouOneDriveDesktopmlpix2pixHDfire.mp4: No such file or directory`

Comment: char \ has special meaning in text in Python (but also in other languages) - ie. `\n` for new line, `\t` for tab - and you may have to  use double \\ in path - like `"C:\\Users\\..."` or you should use prefix `r` for `raw text` - like `r"C:\Users\..."`

Comment: Double Backslash returns:
`creating the dataset structure
ffmpeg -v 16 -i C:\Users\cadou\Downloads\fire.mp4 -q:v 2 -vf "scale=iw*736/ih:736, crop=1280:736" C:\Users\cadou\OneDrive\Desktop\ml\pix2pixHD/datasets/fire_dataset/train_frames/frame-%06d.jpg -hide_banner
extracting the frames
C:UserscadouDownloadsfire.mp4: No such file or directory`

Raw Text returns:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\cadou\OneDrive\Desktop\ml\pix2pixHD\extract_frames.py", line 18, in <module>
    raise Exception("video does not exist")
Exception: video does not exist`